# Spring MongoDB query performances

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I want to understand in depth how the springframeworks mongodb works

so assume i have a index in my database a compound index of 2 fields a,b

Now these are the queries i write i want to know which of these will hit the index and some idea on performance and which is the best type to use

```
1. Query q = new Query()
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where(a).is("val")); 
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where(b).is("val2"));

2. query.addCriteria(Criteria.where(a).is("val").andOperator(Criteria.where(b).is("val2")))

3. query.addCriteria(Criteria.where(a).is("val").and(b).is("val2"))
```

What is the difference between 2 and 3.
Will all of these variation hit the correct index
Some Best Practices around the same

Comment: Turn on query logging for spring data MongoDB to check what is the difference and use those queries for performance measurement.

Comment: @Harshit did that but it does not show if we are hitting the index or not it prints the db query out how can i find that information

Comment: If you turn on query logging then it will log queries, then use explain("executionStats") on that query directly to find out if it uses index or not.

Comment: Indeed this is really just about MongoDB query performance, Spring Data just transforms the java calls into MongoDB queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring-Data (MongoDB) does not influence the decision of how the query should be executed.

> For a query, the MongoDB (server) query optimizer chooses and caches the most efficient query plan given the available indexes

**Reference:** [Query Plans](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-plans/)

Exception:

> Call [cursor.hint(index)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.hint/#cursor.hint--) on a query to override MongoDB's default index selection and query optimization process

Answering to your question: Query planner chooses the best strategy based on your query. No matter how you define it, MongoDB will analyze it and shape it before the execution.

They are equivalent for MongoDB:

```
{"a": "val", "b":"val2"} 
{"a": "val", "$and":[{"b":"val2"}]} 
{"$and":[{"a": "val"}, {"b":"val2"}]}
```

Run `db.collection.find({...}).explain()` for each query for more details.